# using arithmetic functions in custom GraphDB ruleset

Tags: owl, rules, reasoning, graphdb

I want to add a custom rule to the OWL-2-RL ruleset (*builtin_owl2-rl.pie*) that establishes a `isOppositeDirectionOf` object property between vectors that are in opposite direction to each other. I would think it should look something like this:

```
Id: oppositeDirectionVector_rule
     v1 <rdf:type> <cad:Vector>
     v1 <cad:x> v1x            // example data property for v1x: "1.0"^^xsd:double
     v1 <cad:y> v1y
     v1 <cad:z> v1z
     v2 <rdf:type> <cad:Vector>
     v2 <cad:x> -v1x
     v2 <cad:y> -v1y
     v2 <cad:z> -v1z
    -------------------------------
    v1 <cad:isOppositeDirectionOf> v2
```

Without the minuses, this rule does work to create `isSameVectorAs` object properties. 
Is there a way I can use basic arithmetic functions on data properties in rules?

Comment: And I would also like to know if its possible to create new instances (also called individuals in Protégé) via custom rules in `.pie` files. I have only seen corollaries (what's below the ---- line of a rule) being used to establish new links between existing things.

Comment: I understand `Constraint`, but what is `[Cut]` and `[Context]` mean next to an Axiom (what's above the ---- line of a rule)? I can't seem to google that...

Comment: Context is just used to restrict the result of one rule to others is input if the share the same context.

Comment: The syntax you used is clearly wrong. And given that something like `BIND` isn't possible, I don't think its currently possible. Or at least, it's not mentioned in the docs, you could try whether it works nevertheless.

Comment: The only solution I see right now is to use a SPARQL Update query. Clearly, it's unclear how to combine this with the rule inference given that a fix-point iteration is usually done, thus, a single SPARQL query might lead to an incomplete result (very likely in my opinion, but depends on the rest of the data). Running it after the OWL RL materialization, then re-run the OWL RL materialization and compare the number triples in the triple store - that would be my way.

Comment: Thanks @AKSW. Do you know where the docs are for rules that GraphDB understands in a .pie file? I can't seem to find it.
Do you know if I can somehow define a SPARQL query that is to be executed automatically after importing things? I would prefer an automatic query over having to send it actively for what I was trying to achieve with the arithmetic operations.

Comment: well, everything is explained in the [docs](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/reasoning.html#rule-format-and-semantics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use basic arithmetic functions in the rules. Due performance reasons the GraphDB rule engine works with the internal database identifiers, but not the actual RDF values i.e. internal id `10001` instead of `"1"^^xsd:double`. Thus, the only supported variable comparison operations are if the two internal identifiers are equal or not equal.

**Edit following the comment below**: [GraphDB's Plugin API](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/plug-in-api.html) is the only mechanism to integrate your code with the database. A plugin can materialize for every statement with `?s <cad:x> ?o` predicate a new statement `?s <cad:oppositeX> -?o`. Unfortunately, it should handle also the deletes.

Comment: I see, thanks @vassil_momtchev. Do you think there might be a chance to understand these internal ID mappings? Then I could try to use those to trigger something if one value is `"1"^^xsd:double` and the other one is the negative version of it `"-1"^^xsd:double` by comparing their internal IDs instead of actually applying arithmetics.